# R SQLite Access Fails Because of Netdrive - Solutions / Workarounds?

Tags: windows, r, sqlite, networking

I am using the RQDA package which saves files as SQLite databases. To access these files with the package works as long as I do not put them on a netdrive which I need to do because people should be able to work from different computers.

Does anyone (experienced such problems) knows a solution to this?

Comment: Is there any error message showing up? This could help us to help you :)  A "netdrive" is a harddisk on a server I suppose? Could you also provide the code you used for loading ?

Comment: - RQDA has a GUI, so no code :-) - a 'netdrive' is some harddisk which is in windows usually for the user handled like a normal local partition ... "C:\" , "D:\", "Z:\" - RQDA itself uses the "RSQLite" package

Comment: The error produced says something about me having no rights to access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sofar I dicovered 2 solutions:

1) Beeing a little more persuasive in Windows: Right Click -> Proporties -> Security -> Extended -> Change Permissions -> Edit ... and then edit it

2) Make local copies and put them back after edit.

These solutions are far from perfect but I do not know others at the moment. Maybe there is also a way to change the behaviour of the DBI or RSQlite package functions?.